# How to disable a sequence in oracle

Tags: oracle, sas, sequence

I have a scenario where I need to insert records in Oracle via SAS.
The table contains sequence, so for inserting every record I need to first connect to Oracle and fetch the sequence(nextval option).

I want to reduce this connect time(to push 1k records, connect 1K times).

Another problem is I cant simply read max sequence and alter the sequence later with the count of records required to be pushed as there are concurrent other users who pushes the data from other systems.

So I need a help here to disable the sequence? Instead of locking the table itself.

Comment: How are you inserting records ? LIBNAME ? Proc SQL ? Proc APPEND ?  You should have no concerns as to the specific sequence value Oracle nextval delivers.

Comment: If inserting 1k records requires 1k roundtrips, you should perform bulk inserts instead. Combining this with the trigger technique in @Littlefoot's answer should give you a tremendous speedup.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think that you can *disable* it. What you could do is to create a database trigger which will take care about inserting its value. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, col varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_test;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := nvl(:new.id, seq_test.nextval);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values ('Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID COL
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
         2 Foot

SQL>
```

As you can see, you don't have to fetch its value first, database will take care about it. Note that performance probably will suffer if you load A LOT of data, as the trigger will fire for each row inserted.

For users who use the "old" approach (what you currently have), nothing changes:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, col) values (seq_test.nextval, 'Stack');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID COL
---------- --------------------
         3 Stack
         1 Little
         2 Foot

SQL>
```

See if it helps.

Comment: Hi, there is a performance issue associated with it. My only concern is performance hence i dont want to go to loop or fetching nextval everytime.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about pushing to the database, you do not *need* to fetch the sequence `nextval`. Just use it in your `INSERT` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE vaibhav (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    data VARCHAR(100)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE vaibhav_seq;

INSERT INTO vaibhav(id, data)
    VALUES (vaibhav_seq.nextval, 'foo');
INSERT INTO vaibhav(id, data)
    VALUES (vaibhav_seq.nextval, 'bar');

SELECT id, data FROM vaibhav;

  ID DATA
---- ----------
   1 foo
   2 bar
```

Comment: I had tried this but as I need to read nextval everytime, it takes lot of time and performance gets impacted.

Comment: Would a single `SELECT` to retrieve 1k ids, then 1k `INSERT` using the ids you just fetched be ok performance wise?

Answer (score 0):

If you know, N, the number of records in SAS that you need to insert, you can perform a pass through query to obtain N nextval values from the sequence.

```
%let N_SEQ_NEEDED = 1000;

Proc SQL;
  connect to oracle …;
  create table work.sequence_numbers as select * from connection to oracle (
    SELECT 
      ROWNUM n,
      THE_NEEDED_SEQUENCE.nextval sequence_value
    FROM   ( 
      SELECT 1 arbitrary_alias
      FROM   dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= &N_SEQ_NEEDED
    )        
  );
```

CONNECT BY technique from http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques

The is no guarantee on the sequential nature of the N nextval values -- you just need to know they are unique and will never be repeated in any future nextval retrieval.

Merge or update your SAS data set, assigning the retrieved sequence_values to the sequence column in the data set and then perform the INSERT into Oracle via your SAS code.

Comment: Hi Richard, will try this option. Seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the 1000 `NEXTVAL` in a single query, this should be fast.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE vaibhav_seq;

WITH t(n) AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM t
        WHERE n < 1000)
SELECT vaibhav_seq.NEXTVAL FROM t;
```

You can then use them with your `INSERT` statements.